# size chart not display after easy tab on product view page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view

I would  like to show size chart after easy tab Block now its showing in easy tabs but when I call it out of block  **easy tabs** By 
this Code

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/sizechart.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

its Showing Source Code.
how can I call it from out  easy tab Block ?

Answer (score 2):

**Kindly visit below URLs, Hope it's help for you**

> Add custom tabs to product page
>
> https://www.ubertheme.com/docs/add-custom-tabs/
>
> If you want to use size chart extension,try this
>
> https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-product-sizechart.html
>
> Live Demo URL of above extension
>
> http://demostore.kersstech.com/magento-extension/collection/demo-product-2.html?___store=ktm1sc&___from_store=ktm1cbs

Comment: Above extension working as per my requirement,thank you